# How to serve a Laravel project without Homestead?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I am beginning on Laravel and I have a quick question.

I am going to undertake a small test. I will be developing on Laravel under a Mac with Homestead and a Vagrant box.

My test project is going to be ran on an Ubuntu 16.04 with Php 7.

How can it be ran without Homestead or Vagrant? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **laravel valet**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet

Or **php artisan serve**

Comment: Thanks. If I copy my files and deliver to them. Will they just be able to go to the browser and access the local project on their Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Sorry I am not expert in Ubuntu but I think if they have php server running and set properly there will be no problem at all.

Comment: Cool. Thanks I will make some tests before hand.

Answer (score 0):

First, download and install [lnmp](https://lnmp.org/).
Then edit your nginx.conf file, copy the configuration from homestead to the new server.
Finally, reload the nginx and php-fpm service.